# how to avoid the appearin of <br /> at the endof echo?

Tags: php, json

here is my code below that i use to register a user

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
}   

$con = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);

if($con){
    echo "connection good";
}

$response = array();

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $username);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($row > 0){
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Email or Username already exists.";
}else{
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
    $statement2 = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO accounts (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement2, "sss", $email, $username, $password);
    $result2 = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement2);
    $row2 = mysqli_affected_rows($statement2);

    if($row2 > 0){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Account created successfuly.";
    }else{
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Creation error.";
    }
}

$output = json_encode($response);
echo $output;

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

at the end of the file when i check the localhost it echos "good connection br" which i cant use it with json .. how to avoid it so i caan use the response in jsonobject later

Comment: Check connection with `if (!$con) {
    $response["success"] = FLASE;
    $response["message"] = "Connection error";
}`

Comment: if you want to output json than do not use echo "connection good" as it will give an error when you will try to decode json;

Comment: then how to send the json response without echo ??

Comment: You can use $response = array(); if($connection) $response["con"] = "connection good"

Comment: thats wierd    the output was just < br

Comment: nono , it keep outputing < br to the browser even if there is no word with it

Comment: this <br is kept attached all time to any rreesponse going back to browser

Comment: I have just tried your code there is no problem in it. You might be doing some other things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113329/discussion-between-tahir-and-ahmed-nader).

Comment: its frustrating that it wasnt doing that from hours and frustrating that i cant find it out